# Execute function if user doesn't press button with x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

I'm using a Jquery UI dialog like so:

```
    var $dialog;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('Are you awake?<br/><br/><button>Yes</button>')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Inactivity Monitor'
        });

});
```

This dialog shows every 20 minutes and the user must click 'yes' to continue. I need to have something running behind this so if the user doesn't click 'yes' within 10 minutes, another function is executed (send email to head office).

How could I do this?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `setTimeout();` that will execute that function if reached, and you can set it to a variable so you could disable the timer if the button was clicked.
I've set up a jsfiddle to show you how: http://jsfiddle.net/SrwTP/

**JavaScript:**

```
var buttonTimer = setTimeout("alert('Oh noes! you didnt click the button :(');", 5000);
document.getElementById("timerButton").onclick = function(){ clearTimeout(buttonTimer); };
```

**HTML:**

```
<button id="timerButton">Click me or an alert will popup in 5 seconds!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Dvir, thats great :) I've got it working now so that a dialog box pops up every 20 mins and if the user doesnt click the 'yes' button after 10 mins, it sends information out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout` to get this done. Have a flag variable to identify the user-actions and validate it in the interval-function for sending the email.

For ex:

The follow example will show the alert box for every 3 seconds.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function timeMsg()
{
var t=setTimeout("alertMsg()",3000);
}
function alertMsg()
{
alert("Hello");
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Display alert box in 3 seconds"
onclick="timeMsg()" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```